# Web Api 2 - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an MVC project in my solution, which also has ApiControllers in it.
I have set the project up in IIS and added it to the hosts file.

The route looks like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I added a controller called TestController inside the folder Project.Web/Controllers and it has one method, which simply return a string like this:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

If I try to reach my site via mysite.local/api/test/get i get the following error:

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://mysite.local/api/test/get'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'test'."
}
```

But if I start the website from Visual Studio 17, I am able to reach localhost:portnr/api/test/get without any errors.

I have tried to add `[Route()]` and `[RoutePrefix()]` without any success
I have also tried to move the Apicontroller into Project.Web/Controllers/Api without any success

Does anyone know why I am able to reach it via localhost, but not via domainname?

Regards
David

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the name when you have an Action method with the name `Get`.

You need to revert back your change in the route config to the default configuration. If you wish to use custom routing, please use `Route` annotation.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

API will understand by default, if you go to the URL "`http://sampleweb.com/api/test`", this will call your `Get` method.

Comment: Hi Sulay,

Yes I know that it will understand it by default, but the same problem will happen even if try http://mysite.local/api/test or http://mysite.local/api/test/get

I tried adding routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id} aswell, since we need several HttpGet in the API but we still get the same errormessage.

Comment: Did you have the .net framework registered with your IIS?, as i can see when you run with localhost port is that running with iis express?

Comment: Yes i have .net framework registered with IIS and yes the localhost is running with iis express